# How I disappear mat card when array is empty in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my Angular HTML file code  :

```
<mat-card  *ngFor="let getCartDetail of getCartDetails"  style="margin-bottom: 1em; " >
            <div class="card-container"> 
                <mat-card-title ><h3>{{getCartDetail.title1}}</h3> </mat-card-title>
            </div>
    </mat-card>
```

When "getCartDetails" array is empty, I got an error "Cannot read property 'title1' of undefined."
How I set an empty string to getCartDetail.title1 or can I disappear that when the array is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple methods

**Option 1: Using `*ngIf`**

You could check if the array is defined before using it. Since a single element can't have two structural directives, I'd wrap it in a `<ng-container>`.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="!!getCartDetails && getCartDetails.length">
  <mat-card  *ngFor="let getCartDetail of getCartDetails"  style="margin-bottom: 1em; " >
    <div class="card-container"> 
      <mat-card-title><h3>{{getCartDetail.title1}}</h3> </mat-card-title>
    </div>
  </mat-card>
</ng-container>
```

- `!!getCartDetails` checks if the variable `getCartDetails` is defined. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/784929/6513921) for more info on double-bang `!!`.
- `getCartDetails.length` checks if the array is empty

Here the `<mat-card>` would not be rendered when the condition fails.

**Option 2: Safe navigation operator `?.`**

You could use safe navigation operator `?.` to check if the variable is defined before accessing it's properties.

```html
<mat-card  *ngFor="let getCartDetail of getCartDetails"  style="margin-bottom: 1em; " >
  <div class="card-container"> 
    <mat-card-title><h3>{{getCartDetail?.title1}}</h3> </mat-card-title>
  </div>
</mat-card>
```

Here the `<mat-card>` would be rendered with an empty `<mat-card-title>` when the `title1` is unavailable.

**Option 3: Using `||`**

Statements inside Angular template interpolation `{{ }}` are valid Typescript expressions, so you could use `||` to use an alternate value when the expression fails.

```html
<mat-card  *ngFor="let getCartDetail of getCartDetails"  style="margin-bottom: 1em; " >
  <div class="card-container"> 
    <mat-card-title><h3>{{ getCartDetail.title1 || '' }}</h3> </mat-card-title>
  </div>
</mat-card>
```

Here the `<mat-card>` would be rendered with an empty `<mat-card-title>` when the `title1` is unavailable.

Answer (score 2):

1.You can use a null check in the code with '?'

```
<mat-card  *ngFor="let getCartDetail of getCartDetails"  style="margin-bottom: 1em; " >
        <div class="card-container"> 
            <mat-card-title ><h3>{{getCartDetail?.title1}}</h3> </mat-card-title>
        </div>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use length check in array:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="array && array.length > 0">
  <mat-card *ngFor="let item of array">
  </mat-card>
</ng-container>
```

or u can use Elvis/safe navigation operator

```
 <h3>{{getCartDetail?.title1}}</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-template for this validation, like this:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="getCartDetails.length > 0">
    <mat-card *ngFor="let getCartDetail of getCartDetails" style="margin-bottom: 1em; ">
        <div class="card-container">
            <mat-card-title>
                <h3>{{getCartDetail.title1}}</h3>
            </mat-card-title>
        </div>
    </mat-card>
</ng-template>
```